# Evaluating a series practically

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

I am trying to figure out a practical approach to finding the finite result of an infinite sum - preferably with my HP-50G calculator. For example, if given the following function:

$$i_f(t) = 1.25 + \frac{5}{\pi} \sum_{n=1 (odd)}^{\infty} \left[\frac{\sin 2nt}{n(1 + n^2)} - \frac{\cos 2nt}{1 + n^2} \right]$$

It is of interest to evaluate at $i_f(0)$, so the function becomes:

$$i_f(0) = 1.25 - \frac{5}{\pi} \sum_{n = 1 (odd)}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + n^2}$$

My textbook simply states that the summation portion is $0.720$ (i.e. $\sum 1/(1 + n^2) = 0.720$) to three significant figures. A complication is that the summation iterates using consecutive odd integers.

Is there a way to transform this to the point where I can evaluate it with my calculator? WolframAlpha, for instance, shows the following alternate form:

$$\frac{\pi \sinh(\pi)}{4(1 + \cosh(\pi))}$$

How can I simplify it to that alternate form?

Comment: Replace $n$ with $2k - 1$. Now your summation begins at $k=1$, and you can iterate normally.

Comment: But it seems not $0.720$?

Comment: @Alexis You are right - I have corrected my post.

Comment: @SSS That solves the odd iterating issue, thank you.